# mysql: sum of some of data divided by sum of total data in the same table

Tags: mysql

```
   date          value 
   2012-01-01     124
   2012-01-02     250
   2012-04-21     56
   2012-07-06     198 
   2012-09-24     650
   2013-07-07    1000
```

I would like to "sum" the value from 2012-01-01 to 2012-07-06, and divided by "sum" total from 2012-01-01 to 2013-07-07 in the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(value) FROM yourTable WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-07-06') /
       (SELECT SUM(value) FROM yourTable WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-07-07')
```

or:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-07-06'), value, 0)) /
       SUM(IF(date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-07-07'), value, 0))
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I want!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sum(if(date between ... and ..., value, 0)/sum(value)
from table where date beteen ... and ...
```

Use the smaller date range in the if(), the wider in the where condition.